# How to fetch information from database, from current position?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, exists

I am beginner and bit confused that how to get information from database from current position. Let an example, In DATABASE: three rows..id (Primary Key), userid and info and having data on almost 400 id`s.

Now Say if user type userid: abc which is on 120th position in id.

I want to display all id`s and userid`s after 120th position. say from 121st id to 400th id.

I create a code for this, but it not working at all. Please help and Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
      $userid=$_POST['refuserid'];
$sql = "SELECT id, userid, fullname FROM personal WHERE > (select id from personal where userid='$userid')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {

       echo "<tr>";

       echo "<td>" .$row["id"]. "</td>";
       echo "<td>" .$row["userid"]. "</td>";
       echo "<td>" .$row["fullname"]. "</td>";

$i++;      
       }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
  }
?>  <form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="refuserid" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

**Connection:**

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "gold99");
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: You are mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_error()` that needs to read as `mysqli_error($conn)` and `MYSQL_NUM` to `MYSQLI_NUM`. You cannot mix those two together.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I corrected code...but again not working

Comment: Are you relying on `$data['id']` to take the ID you enter in your form? `<input type="text" name="id" />`

Comment: @AnkitBhatanagar , what you told, You retrieve all the row after the matching userid='abc' or other userid like xyz,mno and so on, in this table ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I thought you a bit confused. Actually I want all that data which is below given user id. ABC is an example only. If I have more than 200 records below ABC than how I`ll show that? This is the question, simple.

Comment: So, what is this used for then `<input type="text" name="id" />`? You're not assigning it in your PHP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You suggest!! Can I remove this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you help me in this?

Comment: Not right now, I'm headed to sleep. I'll try when I can later on if nobody has helped figure it out.

Comment: Shortest way is `SELECT * FROM personal WHERE userid = 'abc'` - I don't see why you want/need an INNER JOIN. If using your form, `SELECT * FROM personal WHERE userid = '$userid'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `join` query

```
$sql = "SELECT a.id, a.userid, a.fullname FROM personal as a INNER JOIN personal as b ON a.id > b.id AND b.userid = 'abc'";
```

Comment: @AnkitBhatanagar  i updated my answer , please try replacing your query with my one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.userid 
FROM personal p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM personal p1 
              WHERE p.id > p1.id AND p1.userid = 'abc'
             );
```

Comment: But what is p.id and p.userid. Actually what is the mean of "p" here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$sql = "SELECT id, userid FROM personal where id > (SELECT id FROM personal where userid = 'abc')";
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: giving an error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: its not query error try below code
$sql = "SELECT id,cat_name FROM primary_category where id > (SELECT id FROM primary_category where cat_name = 'Travel')";
$data = $cons->query($sql);

$data = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($data as $val ){
 echo $data['id'];
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$ID = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT id, userid FROM personal WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM personal WHERE userid = '{$ID}')";
$data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: but how to echo all records below that id..?

Comment: @AnkitBhatanagar Your question says that you want to display all the records after a certain id, this code will do that only. What else do you want to display?

Comment: I thought you a bit confused. Actually I want all that data which is below given user id. ABC is an example only. If I have more than 200 records below ABC than how I`ll show that? This is the question, simple.

Comment: @AnkitBhatanagar You should edit your question then, it says "_I want to display all id`s and userids` after 120th position. say from 121st id to 400th id_" . Anyway if want the records below ABC then just change the greater than sign with less than. Hope it helps.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 49.

Comment: Line no 49: if (mysqli_num_rows($result))